# store details in windows phone 8 using sqlite?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I want to store information from the NFC tag I read and store in the database and show it all in another page but I am having problem in using implementing sqlite.I cant add the information to the database using sqlite.
Below is my checkin class from where I read from the NFC tag

```
 public partial class Checkin : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ProximityDevice _device;
    private long _subscriptionIdNdef;

    public static double Latitud_do { get; set; }
    public static double Longtitude_do { get; set; }
    public static string latitude { get; set; }
    public static string longtitude { get; set; }
    public static string Floor_st { get; set; }
    public static string Zone_st { get; set; }

    History store = new History();


    public Checkin()
    {
        InitializeProximityDevice();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetLogStatus(string newStatus)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { if (LogStatus != null) LogStatus.Text = newStatus; });
    }

    private void SetFloorStatus(string newStatus)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { if (FloorStatus != null) FloorStatus.Text = newStatus; });

    }



    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" ");
    }


    private void InitializeProximityDevice()
    {
        _device = Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        if (_device != null)
        {
            _subscriptionIdNdef = _device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler);

        }

    }


    private void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
    {
        var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
        var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(rawMsg);


        ////// Loop over all records contained in the NDEF message
        foreach (NdefRecord record in ndefMessage)
        {

            if (NdefTextRecord.IsRecordType(record))
            {
                // Convert and extract URI info
                var textRecord = new NdefTextRecord(record);
                string[] str = textRecord.Text.Split('|');

                var Floor_st = str[0];
                var Zone_st = str[1];
                var latitude = str[2];
                var longtitude = str[3];
                Latitud_do = double.Parse(latitude);
                Longtitude_do = double.Parse(longtitude);



                SetLogStatus("Floor: " + Floor_st + " Zone: " + Zone_st );
                SetFloorStatus("Longitude: " + latitude + "   Longitude: " + longtitude);
                //store.AddDb(Floor_st, Zone_st, Latitud_do, Longtitude_do);


            }
        }
      }
 }
```

Below here is the main dbhelper class for the main sqlite functions

```
public class DbHelper
{

    SQLiteConnection dbConn;

    public async Task<bool> onCreate(string DB_PATH)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
            {
                using (dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
                {
                    dbConn.CreateTable<historyTableSQlite>();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //retrieve all list from the database
    public ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> ReadHistory()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            List<historyTableSQlite> myCollection = dbConn.Table<historyTableSQlite>().ToList<historyTableSQlite>();
            ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>(myCollection);
            return HistoryList;
        }
    }

    // Insert the new info in the histrorytablesqlite table. 
    public void Insert(historyTableSQlite newcontact)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                dbConn.Insert(newcontact);
            });
        }
    }



}
```

below is the class from where I read all the information

```
public class ReadAllContactsList
{
    DbHelper Db_Helper = new DbHelper();
    public ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> GetAllHistory()
    {
        return Db_Helper.ReadHistory();
    }
}
```

}

And last is the class where I want to show all the information I have stored

```
ublic partial class History : PhoneApplicationPage
{





    // string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> DB_HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>();

    public History()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void ReadHistoryList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllContactsList dbhistory = new ReadAllContactsList();
        DB_HistoryList = dbhistory.GetAllHistory();//Get all DB contacts
        ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();//Latest contact ID can Display first

    }


    public void AddInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
        Db_helper.Insert(new historyTableSQlite(

             ));

    }
```

}

I followed the following post but still struglling
http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2014/08/windowsphone-8-sqlite-storing-data-in.html
Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: "Still struggling" isn't very specific. What's your question?

Comment: I want to add all the attributes from the checkin class in the database and then show them out in the history class

Comment: @vivekshahi That is not a question, those are requirements.  What part of the your code is not working or having trouble with?

Comment: How DO I implement  AddInfo() in the History class?